How to get live camera streaming?
In WWDC24 new CameraFrameProvider in available for business developer, how to get the current camera frame by this API?

Business developers don’t have access to this, enterprise developers do, there is a big difference.

First create your CameraFrameProvider instance
private let cameraTracking = CameraFrameProvider()

Then receive the new camera frame:
for await i in cameraTracking.cameraFrameUpdates(for: .supportedVideoFormats(for: .main, cameraPositions: [.left]).first!)! {
    let imageBuffer:CVPixelBuffer = i.primarySample.pixelBuffer
}

Convert to UIImage if needed:
import UIKit
import CoreVideo
import CoreImage

extension UIImage {
    static func imageFromPixelBuffer(pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer) -> UIImage? {
        let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
        let ciContext = CIContext(options: nil)
        
        guard let cgImage = ciContext.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent) else {
            return nil
        }
        
        return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
    }
}

